# Android Recycler View generating dialog box

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, scrollview

I have a recycler view with 10 15 items in it. As soon as the activity which contains recycler view open I want to check if some particular item is present in the list or not. If present I am showing a dialog box.

Everything works fine if the item is on top of the list i.e if the recycler view showing 5 items at a time so if that particular item is in top 5 items the dialog box appears but if that item is at after 5th position then dialog box only appears after scrolling down. Below is the code.

```
   @Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final CandidateViewHolder holder, int position) {
   if (holder.userId.equals(data.getId())) {
            DialogBox dialogBox = new DialogBox(mContext),                 
            dialogBox.generateDialogBox();

        }
}
```

I am sure there must be a way to do this probably I am doing it wrong. So any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`onBindViewHolder` only gets called when the view is about to show on the screen, so if you want to check items that doesn't appear on the screen you need to search in your dataset and not in the `onBindViewHolder` method